# Unable to download a Sitecore file in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, sitecore

I have a Xamarin mobile project setup with the Sitecore MobileSDK (WebAPI) and can browse through the items using the ReadItemsRequestWithPath method. Now I am trying to download a pdf file that is stored in the 'media library' directory. I have tried the following:

```
private async void DownloadFile() 
{
    try
    {
        string instanceUrl = "https://sitecoredev10.myapp.org";
        using (var demoCredentials = new SecureStringPasswordProvider("username", "password"))
        using
        (
          var session =
                    SitecoreWebApiSessionBuilder.AuthenticatedSessionWithHost(instanceUrl)
                                                .Credentials(demoCredentials)
                                                .BuildReadonlySession())
        {
            var request = ItemWebApiRequestBuilder.DownloadResourceRequestWithMediaPath("/sitecore/media library/path/to/file")
                                  .Build();
            Stream response = await session.DownloadMediaResourceAsync(request);

            // Process Stream...
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Exception originalError = e.InnerException;
        Console.WriteLine(originalError.Message); // access original error
        Console.WriteLine(originalError.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting the following exception:

```
[Sitecore Mobile SDK] Unable to download data from the internet
2016-11-03 15:24:53.411 SitecoreDemo.iOS[88136:15581600] Not Found
```

Should I be using a different method other than DownloadMediaResourceAsync? How can I download the file?

Comment: I am not at all familiar with sitecore, but wonder if the space in the path might be an issue? Maybe try replacing the space in "/sitecore/media library/path/to/file" with a %20? i.e. "/sitecore/media%20library/path/to/file"